# How to use ORDER BY and LIMIT on node children but not their parents? Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of `Author` nodes. An `Author` node is the single parent of multiple `Book` nodes.

My goal: To print all `Author` nodes with no order and no limit, with each authors' first three books in alphabetical order.

**Desired output**: (let's pretend book names are a single letter)

```
[
  {
    "name" : "Leo Tolstoy",
    "books": [
      { "name": "A" },
      { "name": "B" },
      { "name": "D" }
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "Charles Dickens",
    "books": [
      { "name": "C" },
      { "name": "E" },
      { "name": "F" }
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "Oscar Wilde
  ...
]
```

**My Problem**:
I tried this:

```
MATCH(author:Author)
WITH author

OPTIONAL MATCH(author)-[:WROTE]->(book:Book)
WITH author, book
ORDER BY book.name
LIMIT 3

WITH author, collect(book) AS books
RETURN collect (
  {
    name: author.name,
    books: books
  }
);
```

But this gives:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "Leo Tolstoy",
    "books": [
      { "name": "A" },
      { "name": "B" },
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "Charles Dickens",
    "books": [
      { "name": "C" }
    ]
  }
]
```

How could I achieve my desired output in Neo4j v3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

This should work:

```
MATCH(author:Author)
OPTIONAL MATCH(author)-[:WROTE]->(book:Book)
WITH author, book.name AS bookName
ORDER BY bookName
WITH author, COLLECT({name: bookName})[..3] AS bookNames
RETURN COLLECT({name: author.name, books: bookNames}) AS result
```

Comment: You'll need an ordering between the optional match and the collect, but yes this works. This is one of several approaches that work for this case, this knowledge base entry covers the others: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/

Comment: Thank you! I understand how to limit books lists per author. But, how could I order the book names within this query? I tried putting `ORDER BY bookNames` after the third line but this didn't seem to change anything

Comment: I have updated my answer so that the book names are sorted.